# scala Future with an explicit return statement

Tags: scala, future

This question is not about refactoring a function to avoid any explicit return statement.

I need to asynchronously run a function with an explicit return statement. For example:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def evaluate(): Future[Int] = Future {
   return 42
}


val t = Await.result(evaluate(), 1 second)

println(t)
```

(running with amm)

If I compile this, I get this error:

```
future_return.sc:8: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(42)
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
   return 42
          ^
Compilation Failed
```

So my first question is why is this failing while simply having

```
def evaluate() = Future { 42 }
```

works ? Is there a profound difference by using `return` that could bypass the `Future` "keyword" before the actual function code?

Second question: how to make it work while keeping the `return` statement?

I tried things like

```
return Future[Int] {42}
```

but I get this error

```
scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [1 second]
```

so not sure I'm going in the correct direction.

Thanks

Comment: To put it in your words: yes, there is a profound difference between `def x: Future[Int] = Future(42)` and `def x: Future[Int] = Future { return 42 }`. The difference is that `return 42` means 'forcibly change the flow of execution and exit from the method with the given value'. It's pretty much exactly like throwing an exception which is guaranteed to be caught by the calling code. This is why you should avoid `return` like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

The error is simple: 42 is not of type `Future[Int]`. To do what you want to do, use `Future.successful(42)`. This is the clean way to create a Success containing  an Int. I suggest you review the concept of monad and if you know monads, re-read what Futures are in Scala.

Your error is rather common, I struggled a lot with stuff like that in my early days of Scala but the best way to avoid these hindrances is to have a clear comprehension of the theory and to know all the tools Scala use to implement it.

edit: Avoid using `return` in Scala.

Comment: I also tried to `return Future.successful(42)` and still get `scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl error`

Comment: Try removing the return keyword

Comment: of course it would work without the `return` keyword. The real `evaluate` function is much more complicated than this trivial example, and rewriting it in order to avoid any return statement is not really an option.

Comment: This is a symptom you're not writing good Scala code. If you really don't want to refactor your code, you should try to wrap your function inside another local function that does Future.successful(evaluate()) or something like that. But I have no direct experience of a similar workaround because one should never be in the condition to do that.